# Is there a way to simulate connection timeout in test?

Tags: java, tcp, tdd

I have an application with a fail-safe routine triggered by connection timeout exception. 
I use `mockserver` for record & replay tests (which means in tests I connect to a real TCP port), but it can do only `read` timeouts.

Is there a way to simulate connection timeout by means of java library, or any external utility?

Answer (score 0):

Here is Linux tool can do this easily : [tc](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/), if you use Linux then you can try it.

Comment: Could you please give an example? The `tc` documentation is silent about timeouts